Styling colors in Resharper's template editor
In Visual Studio 2022 I am using the dark theme.
When editing a Custom pattern with ReSharper, the code is also shown using the dark theme. The problem is that the font colors use different colors than in the text editor. In this example you see in the background (upper part) a snippet of Visual Studio's code editor; the lower part is ReSharper's editing window for Custom patterns:

You see that the annotation gets no special color in the ReSharper dialog. That is okay.
Problematic is the declaration of the function: public class is barely readable. Even worse the following function name (which should be placeholder $ClassName$): It is not readable at all.
Question: How can I configure the colors that ReSharper uses in this template editor?

I am afraid there is no similar Configure colors and fonts option for Pattern template editor. You maybe consider changing the theme to Light.
